JWT storing for user verification
I want to store the user credentials in JWT for login and verification. What is the recommended way to transmit via the network and where to store that JWT at browser end?
I am thinking about either sessionStorage or HTTPOnlyCookie. Is there any other way?
This not about any error resolution. Just want to know about better security practices.

1- JWT as HTTP only cookie is fine.
2- Use appropriate CSP headers.
3- As a backup always verify HTTP REFERRER  and HTTP HOST or ORIGIN headers. Yes they can be spoofed but at least one of them has to match your domain if your user has been a target of CSRF and in that case it won't pass.


Do not store credentials (i.e., passwords) in a JWT, as the JWT is most likely only signed not encrypted.
Do not trust browser (i.e. client provided data) headers Referer and origin.


Do not use JWTs for maintaining a session. https://gist.github.com/samsch/0d1f3d3b4745d778f78b230cf6061452
